# Writing javascript string with multiple levels of quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a little in-line on error message, though I'm not really grasping how the quotes work...please see the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/hS4s8/

I'm trying to load the alternate image in the onerror event

```
var html = '<img src="notarealurl.com/test.jpg" onerror= \"this.src = \"https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/eventlogos/1832816/google.png\" \" />';
```

this html is malformed though. How would I construct it properly with multiple levels of quotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work fine:

```
var html = "<img src='notarealurl.com/test.jpg' onerror='this.src=\"https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/eventlogos/1832816/google.png\"'  />";
$("#container").html(html);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hS4s8/2/)**